# New GFI not working

Tags: wiring

I actually have a problem I solved and I saw a similar problem somebody had posted on this site but since I am new to the site it wouldn't let me comment. So I am posting here my problem and how it got solved.

I had a GFI outlet that stopped working. I purchased a new one of the same brand. I removed the old one labeling the wires as I undid them. I installed the new GFI placing the wires in the same position as the old one.

The indicator light was green showing it was working but the other outlets on the circuit still didn't work.  Other posts indicated that the recepticles come tripped and you have to press hard to get them to reset. I tried this but it didn't work.

I was using a Leviton 20A GFI outlet. This was the same model as I was replacing. Thinking it would be wired the same when I installed the new one I placed the wires in the same place. When I did the status light was green but none of the down line outlets had power.  In talking to a fried he suggested I swap the top and bottom wires on both sides.  I did this and then everything worked.  On closer examination of the old and new outlets discovered that the load and line connectors were swapped.

Comment: Can you post a self-answer explaining what you did to get these to work? I'll upvote it if you do :) (also, adding what make/model GFCI it was would help)

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so anecdotes for their own sake aren't what we do. However, you present this in a Q&A format, **and that definitely is allowed**.  Further, **self-answering your own question is not only allowed, but rewarded.** Brace yourself for reputation both for the question and your own answer. This will quickly get you rep to comment.  To keep that rep, tie an email to your account; browser-cookie-only accounts are easily lost.

Comment: Better, if you have an answer, post an answer (not a comment) on the original question. Duplicate questions aren't ideal. You don't need reputation to _answer_.